# Question about H1B Visa stamping in Italy

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, italy, h1b-visas

I live in US and work here on H1B visa. I am planning to go to Italy for one-week vacation. My passport does not have the latest H1B visa stamped, so I would like to get the visa stamped at one of Consulate in Italy (Rome/Milan). Does anyone have any experience like this? Please share if its worth the trouble or too risky.
- This is my second H1B visa stamping. The previous one I got done in Canada.
- I am an Indian citizen. No immediate plans to travel to home-country so exploring this option.

Comment: Opinion based question. You can only do the risk assessment yourself

Comment: Most likely, the Italian embassy would not issue you a Schengen visa without a ticket to home and back to the US. What happens in the case your H1b visa stamping goes south at the Italian consulate in Rome?, they consider this while issuing you a Schengen visa.

Comment: I would have voted to close as off topic in favor of [Expatriates.SE]. Whatever this questions problems, I don't find it to be a matter of opinion  (@SheikPaul and other close voters).

Comment: @edocetirwi on the other hand, if the traveler has the means to get himself home to India in the event of a visa refusal at the US consulate in Italy, the Italian consulate in the US could credibly issue the visa.

Comment: To be granted a Schengen visa, the embassy requires proof of US Visa or permanent residency and they stated explicitly that an H1B approval is **NOT** considered a visa. Norwegian Embassy FAQ _**My H1B has expired. Can I attach my H1B  approval notice and US visa appointment confirmation to my application  to fulfill the requirement for a valid US visa**? No, as this document clearly states, ”this is not a valid visa”. You must have renewed your H1B before applying_.

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone. I am less worried about getting rejected for Schengen visa application. Because if I do then I just won't go for this trip. I am more worried about going to Italy and getting rejected for US visa stamping in Italy because then I will be left stranded. In that case, I would have to travel to India to get my visa stamped at short notice, with no advance planning + at exorbitant cost for last-minute flights.